# Binning in pandas starting from specific date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, binning

I am trying to bin values according to dates. The dataframe looks like this

```
        type     event_date
43851   MEDIUM 2017-10-09 13:28:33
43852     HIGH 2017-10-09 14:19:49
43853     HIGH 2017-10-09 14:23:25
43854     HIGH 2017-10-09 14:24:18
43855   MEDIUM 2017-10-09 14:25:31
43856      LOW 2017-10-09 14:25:33
43857   MEDIUM 2017-10-09 14:25:33
43858      LOW 2017-10-09 14:25:38
```

I would like to bin from the a specific date and count occurrences of every `type` every half an hour. I tried with

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='30T',key='event_date'), 'type'])
grouper['other_col'].count()
```

which does almost exactly what I want

```
event_date           type
2017-10-09 13:00:00  MEDIUM      1
2017-10-09 14:00:00  HIGH        3
                     LOW         2
                     MEDIUM      2
```

I would like to

1. Start from specified hour (in my case it would be first occurrence of `LOW` - 12 hours = 02:25:33) and not the first available hour rounded down.
2. Display also the empty intervals

Comment: You can display the empty intervals by using the resample command. E.g. `df.resample('hour', on='other_col').sum().fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`

```
starting_hour = (df[df.type=='LOW'].head(1).event_date - dt.timedelta(hours=12)).item()
intervals = pd.cut(df.event_date, pd.date_range(start=starting_hour , freq='30T', periods=49))

43851    (2017-10-09 13:25:33, 2017-10-09 13:55:33]
43852    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43853    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43854    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43855    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43856    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43857    (2017-10-09 13:55:33, 2017-10-09 14:25:33]
43858    (2017-10-09 14:25:33, 2017-10-09 14:55:33]
```

to include only left values, you can

```
df['i'] = intervals.transform(lambda k: k.left)

43851   2017-10-09 13:25:33
43852   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43853   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43854   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43855   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43856   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43857   2017-10-09 13:55:33
43858   2017-10-09 14:25:33
```

Then you can groupby intervals and use `count()`

```
df.groupby(['i', 'type']).count()
```

*Just notice that you are using 30 minutes interval, so there will be lots of empty rows.*